# 外部サーバにあるJavaScriptファイル読み込む場合、処理内容はどこで実行されますか？

Tags: javascript

**下記のような場合**
・hoge.js内に記述した処理はどこで実行されるのでしょうか？

```
<script src="https://example.com/hoge.js"></script>
```

---

・案1.クライアントで実行される
・案2.サーバで実行される

読み込んだ後、クライアントで実行されると思っていたのですが、サーバで実行されることはありますか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

サーバサイドで実行されることはありません。クライアント（ブラウザ）で実行されます。

cssやimgタグなどと同じように、
ブラウザによりダウンロードされてブラウザ上で処理が実行されます。

※ Node.jsをサーバサイドJSで使うとは？
例えば典型的なサーバサイドとは、

1. ApacheなどのWebサーバが
2. PHP, Rails, cgiなどに処理を依頼してhtmlなどHTTPレスポンスを生成してもらい
3. それを返却する

Node.jsをサーバサイドJSで使うとは、
1~3全てをNode.js単品で行います。
(実際には、apache + tomcatと同じように、nginx + Node.jsで分業することが多いと思いますが。）

Comment: (こちらの意図を汲んで)Node.jsに言及していただきありがとうございす。サーバサイドJSをこの形式で使用することはあり得ないわけですね